Group and count events within 100ms occurence
I have the following data. I want to return tabled data if the events happened within 100ms, and they match by same hashcode and same thirdPartyId. So essentially the search has to be sorted by each combination of thirdPartyId and hashcode and then compare events line by line to see if the previous line and current happened within 100ms. How should the query look like?
| makeresults format=csv data="startTS,thirdPartyId,hashCode,accountNumber
2024-04-16 21:53:02.455-04:00,AAAAAAAA,00000001,11111111
2024-04-16 21:53:02.550-04:00,AAAAAAAA,00000001,11112222
2024-04-16 21:53:02.650-04:00,BBBBBBBB,00001230,22222222
2024-04-16 21:53:02.650-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,12121212
2024-04-16 21:53:02.730-04:00,DDDDDDDD,00000005,33333333
2024-04-16 21:53:02.830-04:00,DDDDDDDD,00000005,33334444
2024-04-16 21:53:02.670-04:00,BBBBBBBB,00000002,12121212
2024-04-16 21:53:02.700-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,21212121"
| sort by startTS, thirdPartyId
| makeresults format=csv data="startTS,thirdPartyId,hashCode,accountNumber
2024-04-16 21:53:02.455-04:00,AAAAAAAA,00000001,11111111
2024-04-16 21:53:02.550-04:00,AAAAAAAA,00000001,11112222
2024-04-16 21:53:02.650-04:00,BBBBBBBB,00001230,22222222
2024-04-16 21:53:02.650-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,12121212
2024-04-16 21:53:02.670-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,12121212
2024-04-16 21:53:02.900-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,21212121
2024-04-16 21:53:02.730-04:00,DDDDDDDD,00000005,33333333
2024-04-16 21:53:02.930-04:00,DDDDDDDD,00000005,33334444"
| sort _time
| bin _time span=100ms
| stats count by thirdPartyId, hashCode
| where count >=2

Try:
| makeresults format=csv data="startTS,thirdPartyId,hashCode,accountNumber
2024-04-16 21:53:02.455-04:00,AAAAAAAA,00000001,11111111 
2024-04-16 21:53:02.550-04:00,AAAAAAAA,00000001,11112222 
2024-04-16 21:53:02.650-04:00,BBBBBBBB,00001230,22222222 
2024-04-16 21:53:02.650-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,12121212 
2024-04-16 21:53:02.670-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,12121212 
2024-04-16 21:53:02.900-04:00,CCCCCCCC,00000002,21212121 
2024-04-16 21:53:02.730-04:00,DDDDDDDD,00000005,33333333 
2024-04-16 21:53:02.930-04:00,DDDDDDDD,00000005,33334444"
| eval startTS=strptime('startTS',"%F %H:%M:%S.%3N%:z")
| sort hashCode thirdPartyId startTS
| streamstats window=1 current=false list(startTS) AS prevTS BY hashCode thirdPartyId
| eval 
    timeDifference=startTS-prevTS,
    prevEventWI100ms=if(timeDifference<=0.1,1,0)

Explanaition:

| eval ... strptime() converts time to UNIX time to make calculation on time stamp possible; Doku.
| sort by the criteria you provided
| streamstats gets you the time of the previous event with the same criteria; Doku.
| eval calculates difference into timeDifference and then compares it to 100ms and creates boolean into prevEventWI100ms

